# Tabbed Bar Title and Icon space issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have been working on a project where I have included Bottom tabbed bar for android. The spacing between Icon and Title have some issue as they overlap each other.

```
<local:EntryPage Title="Home" Icon="home.png"/>
<NavigationPage Title="Maps" Icon="placeholder.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:MapPage />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
<NavigationPage Title="Order" Icon="list.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:ListPage />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
<NavigationPage Title="Settings" Icon="settings.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:SettingsPage />`enter code here`
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
```

[Tabbed Bar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4uhX.png)

Comment: Not enough space in bottom nav bar

Comment: It was fine before I made few changes with the Grid above it changed the Nav bar. Any work around?

Comment: @user1234 What changes have you done? Have you customized the tabbed page using a renderer? It seems other tabs' texts are even not shown up.

Comment: No, I havent used any renderer for that. I followed [link] https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-official-bottom-navigation-bottom-tabs-on-android/  and the other tab texts show up on clicking.

Comment: @user1234 This will help you create a bottom navigation view on Android. And generally, it should work if you didn't add extra configurations. Could you please offer a sample to help me reproduce the issues on my side?